# Search inside Array of Object by another Array come from client contain list values in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an object contains arrays of **_id** , Like that :

```
attributes:["1","2"],
```

and Product contain a array of object attributes like :

```
product:{ _id:1,name:"test",attributes:[{product_Id:1,attribute_Id:1,value:"A",attribute_Value_Id:3}]
```

I want to make a one Aggregation by #MongoDB in Node  to find all documents that contain that list attributes in collection Products. some thing like

Select * from **products** where **attributes.attribute_Id** contain *attributes*

do you have Any suggestions and thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.products.find({"product.attributes.attribute_Id":{$in:[1,2,3]} })
```

Comment: thanks , its work fine , but could we use and  for more  key like search both price and attribute

Comment: You can do find({ $and:[ { same query for atribute_id }    , { same query for price   }     ]   })   etc.

Comment: If you need to find single product  matching two or more product attributes at the same time check $elemMatch

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) in this way:

Find all documents where `attribute_Id` inside of `attributes` array has values that match into the array

```js
db.collection.find({
  "attributes.attribute_Id": {
    "$in": [ 1, 2 ]
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K8Kfts2hLlE) where I've added a new product with an id that not exists into the array, so is not fetched in the result.

Note that you can use you own array/variable instead of "[1,2]" when you create your query.